# Cucumber preset database

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, cucumber

I have some test in cucumber:

```
And I select "vim" from "category_id"
```

This select filled form database, and test can't be passed without manual insert it to db.
Is there some automatic tool to preset db before testing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the phrasing of your question, you need to populate the db with test values. You can do this with the `db/seeds.rb` file, but a better way is to use factories for your tests. These will create objects in the database for your tests to use. Factory Girl is the best option for this in rails, so try using that: https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl_rails